# From where can I get reference images

Tags: modeling, blend-files

I am very good at modelling but now I need T-pose male, female, animals and vehicles blueprint. Please suggest me websites to get a front and a side view of real-world objects. What I need right now is the front, side and top view of T-posed female.
I know it is not a blender question but I wanted to ask this to a community familiar with 3D. I am not sure of the tags I have used.

Comment: Not really a Blender-specific question. Please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/66773 It's better to post/search something like this on blenderartists.org

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for “3d reference images” seems to find some results.

[image: google search for 3d reference images]